# Weird issue on Jquery .each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a weird issue in my codes

I have something like

```
var test, result;
$(".class td").each(function(){
     test = $(this).find('input').attr('size');
     if(test){
         result = test * 10;
     }
     console.log(result);
})
```

not every `td` has a input fields so `test` could be `undefined`. However, the console will always output a value from the `test` after test is defined.

For example:

```
   undefined (test = undefined)
   undefined (test = undefined)
   undefined (test = undefined)
   200 (test = 20)
   200 (test = undefined)
   200 (test = undefined)
   200 (test = undefined)
```

I am not sure what's going on here. Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: That looks like the output I would expect if only the fourth td has an input... What do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: No, it will always output a value from `result`, as that is what you're console logging ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `result`  in the inner scope rather than holding it in the outer scope, since the first result has value your further iterations still holds the old value and that is what you see.

```
$(".class td").each(function(){
     var result , 
         test = $(this).find('input').attr('size');
     if(test){ //remove this check and you will see NaN for the iterations where test = undefined in your code
         result = test * 10;
     }
     console.log(result);
});
```

You can also avoid looping the td that doesn't have input fields.

```
$(".class td:has(input)").each(...
```

or

```
$(".class td:has(input[size])").each(...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just grab the inputs in the selector, and map the result of each item to an array:

```
var result = $('.class td input').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('size') * 10;
}).toArray();
```